# User reply to one of the phone numbers in twilio sms api

Tags: twilio

The functionality requires specific data in the case if a user respond to a message sent to him. suppose a user has responded or replied with something like STOP or UNSUBSCRIBE or may be START, I need to have some specific response for the message on which the user replied.

Is there any way to do this ?

Exactly what response does twilio provides to the **request url** provided for the phone number on twilio account ?

Please inform regarding the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can find the description of [the request Twilio makes to your application in the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request).

In brief, the parameters look like this:

```
Parameter   Description
MessageSid  A 34 character unique identifier for the message. May be used to later retrieve this message from the REST API.
SmsSid      Same value as MessageSid. Deprecated and included for backward compatibility.
AccountSid  The 34 character id of the Account this message is associated with.
From        The phone number that sent this message.
To          The phone number of the recipient.
Body        The text body of the message. Up to 1600 characters long.
NumMedia    The number of media items associated with your message
```

There are more items, depending on certain factors. Again, I recommend you read [the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request) to get all the details.